# Convert Laravel validation rules to html form fields

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

Say I have a validation rules for some `Model`, for example validation for a person model will be:

```
'first_name' => ['required', 'string'],
'last_name' => ['required', 'string'],
'birthday' => ['before:today', 'date'],
'salary' => ['min:0', 'max:2000', numeric],
....
```

So if I wrote that rules, it feels wrong to write the same rules manually but for the HTML form fields like:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" required />
<input type="text" name="last_name" required />
<input type="date" name="birthday" max="2016-06-09"/>
<input type="number" name="salary" min="0" max="2000"/>
```

So if the product owner ask me for change the rules like changing the mandatory fields, or even change the maximum salary from `2000` to `5000`, I have to change it manually in the validation rules and the form itself.

So it makes me wonder, is there any automatic way to convert Laravel validation rules to the HTML form fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse your rules, then loop on the parsed datas for building a form. And then, I suggest you to use partial views for doing the trick.

I already did this for building automatic forms and documentations. So i wrote a Laravel package here : https://github.com/Ifnot/ValidationParser.

In the example of my package you just have to create two files :

- A form blade view (contains the code for parsing the validation)
- A field blade view (used for display a form item)

Comment: I loved the idea, it is what I am looking for, but it seems to be wrong for some validation options.. For validating date in Laravel we need to set `['before:today', 'date']` for example. But in the HTML field I need to see `min="2016-06-09"` instead of `before="today"`. After fixing that this tool will be awesome!

Comment: You cannot generate a form without making your own form generator. So you have to parse (like my package) and build your inputs corresponding to your options.

Answer (score 0):

To have the validation rules be in one place, set the rules to variables. Then, pass the variables into the laravel validation page and in your blade template (html).

So, where you are setting the variable:

```
$MaxSalary = 2000;
```

Next, pass in your variable to the Laravel form validation rules:

```
'salary' => ['min:0', "max:$MaxSalary", numeric],
```

Then, pass it into your blade template form:

```
return view('form', ['MaxSalary' => $MaxSalary]);
```

Then, in your blade template, use the variable:

```
<input type="number" name="salary" min="0" max="{{ MaxSalary }}"/>
```

Comment: It have the same problem as I said. If you want to remove, for example, the max salary rule? You must to remove it manually from the validator rules and from all the form that you have wrote `max="{{ MaxSalary }}"`. Same thing about the `min="0"`...

Comment: My understanding of your question was, there is going to be a max salary, but it could change from `2000` to `5000` or whatever number, depending on what the product owner says. With this new piece of information, my way can still work if you add a second variable, `$SalaryRules`, when set to `true`, can invoke this logic, and when set to `false`, can be a field without rules.

Comment: My question was about how to avoid writing the rules manually in the validator and in the HTML. Not just the salary value. As I said: `changing the mandatory fields, or even...`

Answer (score 0):

Using the methods of an empty Illuminate\Validation\ValidationRuleParser could help.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationRuleParser;

$parser = new ValidationRuleParser([]);

$validationRules = ['username' => 'min:3|max:60']

$explodedRules = $parser->explode($validationRules);

//$explodedRules will be ['username' => ['min:3', 'max:60']]

$ruleToParse = 'min:3';

$minRule = $parser->parse($ruleToParse);

//$minRule will be ['Min', ['3']]
```

With this two, you could iterate over a set of given validation rules and translate them to html attributes. I do exactly this in the following project: https://github.com/arielenter/ValidationRulesToInputAttributes

Comment: ANSWER is not the right place to share your own issue

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33903647)